# javascript .forEach loop with nested code

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have this code:

```
function uploadFiles(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    files = [...fileElem.files]

    files.forEach(uploadFile)

}

function uploadFile(file, i) {

}
```

Now, I want to add code to `files.forEach(uploadFile)`

Pseudo code:
files.forEach(
uploadFile();
console.log(file.name);
)

I looked here: [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)
So I tried:

```
files.forEach(function(uploadFile) {
    uploadFile();
    console.log(file.name); 
})

files.forEach(function (entry) {            
    console.log(entry.name);
    uploadFile(entry);
})
```

But I guess I don't understand how this works. How can I execute the function `uploadFile` and access the properties of `file` in the same codeblock?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: The first try makes no sense (just check the content of `uploadFile`). And the second is missing a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```js
function uploadFiles(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    files = [...fileElem.files]

    files.forEach(extendedUploadFile)
    clearFileInput(fileElem);
}

function uploadFile(file, i) 
{
 ....
}

function extendedUploadFile(file, i)
{
    console.log(file.name);
    uploadFile(file, i);
}

// reset/clear FILE type inputs
function clearFileInput(ctrl)
{
  try
  {
    ctrl.value = null;
  }
  catch(ex)
  { }
  if (ctrl.value) ctrl.parentNode.replaceChild(ctrl.cloneNode(true), ctrl);
}
```

Comment: One more thing: after extendUploadFile has completed successfully, how can I remove files from the `fileElem` control Filelist (so that when user clicks upload button again it won't double submit the file)?

Comment: Thank you. However, that clears the whole filelist, I was looking to only clear the files that have been uploaded successfully. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
files.forEach( file => {
       uploadFile(file);
 });
```

Not sure what `i` meant on upload file, guessing it's an iterator:

```
for(var x = 0; x < files.length){
uploadFile(file[x],x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas pointed out, [Mozilla's forEach documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is sufficient enough to understand how it works.

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
   console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element)
}

[2, 5, 9].forEach(logArrayElements)
```

When you iterate over an array, for each element you get the element, index and the array object being traversed. In your case you don't need the array object being traversed for each element. So you can ignore it and do something like this:

```
function uploadFiles(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    files = [...fileElem.files]
    files.forEach(uploadFile)
}

function uploadFile(file, index) {
    console.log(file.name) (Reach the properties of the file)
    ... (Do the uploading)
}
```